# Send a DM to all the members of a server discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to send a dm to all the members of a server. The code I'm using gives no errors but it isn't working.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, *, message):
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await user.send(message)
                print(f"Sent {user.name} a DM.")
            except:
                print(f"Couldn't DM {user.name}.")
        print("Sent all the server a DM.")
```

Comment: Can you replace `except` with `except Exception as e: print(e)` and post the output?Also - have you set up the needed intents?

Comment: I replaced and it sais sintax error

Comment: I guess that speaks for itself

Comment: ok, now it worked.
output: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

Comment: Yeah that's probably the bot itself, you cannot send a DM to yourself. Have you setup the necessary intents?

Comment: I enabled the intents in the bot application

Comment: You have to enable them in the code too

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot. I didn't know about the intents, searched on the web and found how to do that. Now it's working 

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered but to anyone looking at this in the future:

- Make sure your bot's intents allow it to access members
- Also keep in mind some members have DMs turned off (dms from server members)

hope this helps even a little